# a href возвращает на начало страницы

Tags: html

Есть строка кода с ссылкой, ссылки нет, так как она будет вызывать функцию.
Но есть проблема, при нажатии на нее страница возвращается в начало страницы.

```
<a href="#"><Icon28Favorite /></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Предотвратить можно двумя способами точно

1. На js в обработчике клика добавить строку `e.preventDefault();` для предотвращения дефолтного поведения клика по ссылке.

   ```
   document.querySelector("#id-of-href").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
       e.preventDefault();
   }, false);
   ```

   или

   ```
   <a href='#' onclick="event.preventDefault()">Click Me</a>
   ```
2. Не использовать ссылку вовсе, а сделать какой-нибудь `span` или `div` или `button`и стилизовать его под ссылку. **Зачем вам ссылка, если по ней нельзя перейти?**